# Getting Ubuntu Package Fresh Install List

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, mirrors, apt-mirror

I go to Cyber Security competitions, in which I am given an image that is tampered with, making it insecure. One of the steps of securing the image is to get rid of "bad" or "unofficial" packages.

What I want to know is how far off from a clean, fresh installation the current machine is, and look at a human-friendly list of deltas.

I want to do this by getting a list of packages that would be installed on a fresh install, and comparing it to the list of actually installed packages on the machine I am working on.

How do I get that list of fresh install packages?

I need answers for both Ubuntu server and Ubuntu desktop. (Both would be LTS versions.)

Comment: Currently there are 3 LTS with support, 16.04, 14.04 and 12.04 (until April). All have different packages.

Answer (score 0):

`dpkg --get selections | grep install` will give you the list of packages (approx 3500-4000 on an Ubuntu Desktop system) that is apt-marked for installation on your system.

Note that this may be slightly different from what *actually is* currently installed. Apt looks for that delta each time it runs, and tries to install or remove any changes.

Another method is to use `dpkg -l`. Both methods list the contents of the dpkg database, with differing levels of detail and with different output formats.